# Forward declaration of inherit class

Tags: c++, c++11

The programm below is about polymorphism. It just changes the status of a door between open and closed. My problem is that i can't switch the status in my class "Open" to closed since the class "Close" is below my class "Open".

How can i forward declare the class "Close" that it will work properly? (since a normal forward declaration like 'class Close;' doesnt seem to work)

```
class Status;

class Door {
    private:
        Status* currentStatus;
    public:
        void setStatus(Status*);
        void opendoor();
        void closedoor();
};

class Status {
    public:
        virtual void opendoor(Door* s)=0;
        virtual void closedoor(Door* s) = 0;
};

class Open : public Status {
    public:
        void opendoor(Door* s) {
            return;
        }
        void closedoor(Door* s){
            s->setStatus( new Close() ); //Error here
            return;
        }
};

class Close : public Status {
    public:
        void opendoor(Door* s) {
            s->setStatus( new Open() );
            return;
        }
        void closedoor(Door* s){
            return;
        }
};

void Door::opendoor() {
    currentStatus->opendoor(this);
    return;
}

void Door::closedoor(){
    currentStatus->closedoor(this);
    return;
}

void Door::setStatus(Status* x) {
    delete currentStatus;
    currentStatus = x;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Just put the definition of `void Open::closedoor(Door*);` below the definition of `class Open`

Comment: Move Open and Close to different compilation units. Like Open.cpp and Close.cpp. It will work like charm.

Comment: This is possibly the worst case of pseudo-java I've ever seen.   Why not use state (e.g. a `bool` member) to indicate whether something is open or shut, rather than having to morph an object from one type to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest would be to separate the class from the implementation:  first declare all the classes.  Then only the implementation of the member functions.

```
class Status;
class Door {
    ...
};
class Status {
    ...
};

class Open : public Status {
    public:
        void opendoor(Door* s) override; 
        void closedoor(Door* s) override; 
};

class Close : public Status {
    public:
        void opendoor(Door* s) override; 
        void closedoor(Door* s) override; 
};
...
void Open::closedoor(Door* s){
     s->setStatus( new Close() ); //no more error here
     return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess the 'override' should be the trick in this exercise. But do i really need it here, since it would work without the 'override' like the other said in their comments?

Comment: You're welcome.  The order of declaration makes the trick.  The override is optional: it's a good practice for the definition of virtual functions in the derived classes, to avoid nasty errors, due to a simple typo.

Answer (score 1):

Define the member function that needs the full definition of `Close` **after** the full implementation of `Close`. For example,

```
void Open::closedoor(Door* s)
```

should be defined outside your class, after `class Close`. That's because in the line

```
s->setStatus( new Close() )
```

the compiler needs to know the full definition of `Close`, as it tries to constructs an object of type `Close`.